# How to run query when browser closes?

Tags: php

I have script below. When we close window, user logout is working, but in database the status didn't change. I mean status 1 shows user is online and status 0 shows offline, but status didn't change when user logs out through window close.

If we click on "logout" button, onlu then status changes.

```
if($_SESSION['username'] != "admin")
{
    $timeout = 1; 
    $logout_redirect_url = "logout.php"; 
    $timeout = $timeout * 60; 

    if(isset($_SESSION['start_time']))
    {
        $elapsed_time = time() - $_SESSION['start_time'];
        if ($elapsed_time >= $timeout)
        {
            $db->query($strQuery1);
            header("Location: $logout_redirect_url");
        }
    }

    $_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
}
```

Comment: From the description of your question I would assume that the browser is not redirecting. Does the redirect happen in the browser? Also if you properly indent your code you might spot a logical or control-flow error more easily if there is any.

Comment: How should your database gain knowledge about the user closing his browser?

Comment: @user1755316 please format your code before posting for better reading.

Comment: A database cant see if you close your browser unless you shoot a variable to your database telling it closes. And I dont think thats possible, cause this is an action that happens outside of the browser processing.  What you can do better is destroy the session after an ammount of time, instead of closing the browser anyway.

Comment: There is **no reliable way** of knowing that user closed the browser. Note the bolded part. Therefore, any feature relying on knowing whether the browser was closed or not will be, at best, terribly inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the better way
If you want dynamically know if an user is currently on your web site or not, you can set a value last connect in your database (which save a datetime value). This value "last connect" will be reset when user reload a new page, may be when you apply the test to see if he is currently logged.

After that, you create a cron that read the value "last connect" and you can know if the user is timeout.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is add a javascript `window.onBeforeUnload` event, that triggers an ajax call and updates your query.

But it is not safe, since its only client side, but it's worth a shot.

Another way is checking for session times, and, if a session has not been refreshed in your desired timeout, then logout the user manually.

PS: You should also take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) manual, will be helpfull.